# Probability of finding adjacent colored squares in a line of white squares

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So this question has a small science background, but the problem itself is purely mathematical. Consider a one-dimensional row of squares, some are white, some are blue. The blue squares represent water, and the white ones represent some other irrelevant compound. If there are $N$ total squares and $n$ water squares, and you are given the concentration of water in the solution (say it is any multiple of $10\%$ from $0\%$ to $100\%$), how would you calculate the probability for each concentration that two water squares are touching? How would you calculate the average number of water-water bonds in each concentration? Two adjacent blue squares represents one water-water bond.

EDIT:  My model in one-dimension seems to be working to my liking, and I would now like to extrapolate it to two and three dimensions.  I will be posting my personal results/progress here, but what is the best way to move this into higher dimensions?

Comment: If we already know the number $N$ of squares and the number of water squares $n$, why should we care about the water concentration?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that I'm looking for the probabilities of finding a water-water bond in certain concentrations of water, aka solutions where n/N is a multiple of 0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will suppose that the locations of the blue squares are "random," with all choices of $n$ blue squares from the $N$ total squares equally likely. We will use the method of *indicator* random variables.

For $i=1$ to $N-1$, let $X_i=1$ is there is water at $i$ and at $i+1$, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $X=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N-1}$ is the number of times a blue is followed by a blue. You asked for $E(X)$. By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(X)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_{N-1}).$$

All the $X_i$ have the same expectation. The probability that the $i$-th square is blue **and** the $i+1$-th square is blue is $\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{n-1}{N-1}$.
Multiply by $N-1$ to get $E(X)$. We conclude that
$$E(X)=\frac{n(n-1)}{N}.$$

**Remark:** Note that the $X_i$ are **not** independent, but for linearity of expectation, that doesn't matter. To a fair degree, it is this fact that makes the method powerful. It enables us to bypass the possibly difficult problem of finding the distribution of $X$, and then wading through a mess to calculate the expectation.

Comment: This makes sense to me until the probability part.  I don't have much probability background, could you explain how $\frac{n}{N}*\frac{n-1}{N-1}$ gives the probability that two adjacent squares are blue?  I could easily be missing something, but it seems to give the probability that two random squares are blue.

Comment: It gives the probability that two specific squares are blue. They happen to ne adjacent.  That part of the argument is straightforward, the magic is contained in the linearity of expectation. It makes it possible to find the mean without heavy-duty computation.

Comment: So if I'm understanding the formula correctly, then will the equation $\frac{n}{N}*\frac{n-2}{N-1}$ give the probability that the $i$-th and the $i+1$-th squares are blue?

Comment: The $n-2$ in the formula in the comment is not correct. If $i$ and $j$ are any two distinct numbers between $1$ and $N$, then the probability the $i$-th square and $j$-th square are both blue is $\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{n-1}{N-1}$. Note by the way that my random variables $X_i$ are **not** independent, but that doesn't matter for the expectation calculation.

Comment: Yes, but how does your formula guarantee that the i-th and j-th squares are adjacent?  How does the formula $\frac{n}{N}\frac{n-1}{N-1}$ link back to the $X_{i}$ you defined earlier?  I think $j$ would have to equal $i+1$ for this to be true.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The formula you mention gives the probability that $i$ and $j$ are both blue, for any $i\ne j$. In particular, it is correct when $j=i+1$. That's all we need to calculate expectation.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. We're choosing any two adjacent squares and the probability that they are both blue is $\frac{n}{N}\frac{n-1}{N-1}$. Since there are $N-1$ ways to have two adjacent blue squares, we multiply by $N-1$ to get the expectation value of $X$. Do I have that right? Again, thanks for your patience with my limited probability background, I appreciate it.

Comment: The "Since there are $N-1$ ways" part is not wrong, but the real point is that there are $N-1$ random variables all with the same mean that we are adding up. Indicator random variable arguments are ultimately simple, but they are sometimes a little subtle. You may have seen this sort of argument in the calculation that shows the mean of a binomial is $np(1-p)$.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of arrangements is $N \choose n$.  To find the total number without a pair of water squares together, put the non-water squares in a row.  There are $N-n+1$ places to put water squares (including each end), so there are ${N-n+1 \choose n}$ ways.  The required probability is then $1-\frac {N-n+1 \choose n}{N \choose n}=1-\frac {(N-n+1)!}{n!(N-2n+1)!}\frac {(N-n)!n!}{N!}=1-\frac {(N-n+1)!}{(N-2n+1)!}\frac {(N-n)!}{N!}$

Comment: I like this approach, but doesn't the ${N-n+1 \choose n}$ include some configurations where water squares are touching?

Comment: @JonRuffin:  No.  You have $N-n$ non-water squares.  The two ends plus the $N-n-1$ slots between them make $N-n+1$.  If you put at most one water in each slot, no waters will be touching.  If $2n \gt N+1$ you will run out of slots, which is correct.